# Disable connect.sid in express.js api response

Tags: rest, cookies, express, token

I am developing REST api using the express js. Even though I don't have any session specific code written, in the api response `connect.sid` cookie seems to be getting set. Is this a default behavioue of express.js? I plan to use token based authentication mechanism so I want to disable this completely. Is there an option to disable this completely?

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

app.use(cors());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept, x-xsrf-token');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

// CookieParser should be above session
app.use(cookieParser());

// Express MongoDB session storage
app.use(session({
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: true,
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    store: new mongoStore({
        db: db.connection.db,
        collection: config.sessionCollection
    })
}));

// use passport session
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: So on what routes are you seeing the session cookie being set?

Comment: All of them. Irrespective of whether the user is logged in or no.

Comment: With (mostly) the same code that you're using, I don't see any cookies being pushed by Express (see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/7a2fc8ffa797cfb31f50)).

Comment: I still see the cookie being set from your gist. Using the postman REST client. http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=1941bff

Comment: Are you sure that your browser isn't _sending_ the cookie in the first place? If that's the case, it's basically telling Express to maintain the session and it wouldn't surprise me that Express is setting a cookie because of that.

Comment: @robertklep I am new to the web dev, correct me if I am wrong. I see that whatever api calls I make be it fb graph api, firebase api, the browser always sends the cookie in the request but the response doesn't include any cookie since they are token based. So, I am assuming that there is something in express which makes it always set the cookie in response which is what I don't want. Interestingly, when I remove the express-session code completely, I still see the cookie being set.

Comment: To prevent being misdirected because your browser is sending cookies, you could use a command line tool to make HTTP requests (something like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie)) to see which headers are being returned by your server. It's strange that cookies are still being set when `express-session` isn't even being used; are you sure it's the _response_ and not the _request_ that you're looking at?

Comment: Yes, I was checking the response headers for sure. I tested it out on curl and figured out that since curl doesn't send any cookie, it doesn't receive connect.sid cookie. The browser client that I was using, sends cookie in the request, hence express implicitly sets it in the response. But I didn't want that behaviour either. I solved this by adding a middleware to remove the connect.sid cookie from the response header on all the routes and removing all the session code from app.js. Thanks for your quick responses!

Comment: For other time travelers wondering what, denvercoder9, I mean codebreaker saw, here's a simple middleware API to set the `connect.sid` cookie to a date in the past, which ensures the client discards it entirely: `app.use((req, res, next) => { res.cookie('connect.sid', '', { expires: new Date(0) }); next(); });`